# IF Statements Syntax in Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER likeTr
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE user_id INTEGER;
DECLARE post_id INTEGER;
DECLARE old_user_id INTEGER;
DECLARE old_post_id INTEGER;

SET user_id = NEW.uid;
SET post_id = NEW.pid;

SELECT uid,pid
INTO old_user_id,old_post_id
FROM likes
WHERE user_id = uid AND post_id = pid;

IF (user_id IS old_user_id AND post_id IS old_post_id) THEN
    DELETE FROM likes WHERE pid = post_id AND uid = user_id;
    UPDATE posts SET likes = likes-1 WHERE pid = post_id;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO likes (pid , uid) VALUES (post_id , user_id);
    UPDATE posts SET likes = likes+1 WHERE pid = post_id;
END IF;
END;
```

I'm beginner in triggers mysql, I've wrote this trigger to do some task but when i try to submit it in phpmyadmin it sends an error in line 18 (IF (user_id IS old_user_id AND post_id IS old_post_id) THEN)

I Don't know the reason, any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF (user_id = old_user_id AND post_id = old_post_id) THEN
```

instead of

```
IF (user_id IS old_user_id AND post_id IS old_post_id) THEN
```

Comment: Read the code again, this line is written in the question

Comment: @user3609556:- I read your code. I asked you to replace your code with the answered one! Instead of IS try with =

Comment: sorry i've not understood you, it's working but how can "=" be for comparing not assignment

Comment: @user3609556:- Inside IF it is used as comparison not assignment. Also do mark this as an answer if that worked!